# Включение автоматической переадресации на почте [C# & MailNet]

Tags: c#, email, mail.ru

Всем привет!

На почтах есть замечательная функция - автоматическая переадресация входящий сообщений на другой почтовый ящик ([Инструкция по включению такой штуки](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-45aa9664-4911-4f96-9663-ece42816d746))

Можно ли включать переадресацию на другой почтовых ящик через код? На данный момент использую библиотеку MailNet

**UPD**
Спасибо комментатором. Если вкратце, то MailNet реализует базовое взаимодействие с SMTP, т.е. работа с письмом. Получается, надо делать отправку через API, но вот только как такое реализовать, есть ли где-то готовые решения, ведь список почтовых сервисов невероятно большой

Comment: что значит "провернуть через код"? Что этот код должен сделать и где?

Comment: Представьте, что вы пишете письмо (не электронное, простое) в другой город, вы написали, пошли на почту, отправили. Теперь вопрос: Вы сможете благодаря этому письму, да и вообще всей этой цепочки действий узнать, к примеру какого цвета обои в коридоре? Ну вот и тут примерно тоже самое, не знаю конечно, что за `MailNet`, но там скорей всего простое использование SMTP - некого протокола почтового сервера, который позволяет лишь передавать письма, не более. Вы не сможете через этот протокол настраивать аккаунт, либо просто узнавать его настройки. Нужно это - ищите API конкретного сервиса.

Comment: Еще это называется Сбор почты. И нет, почтовые протоколы здесь не при чем.

Comment: Понял, спасибо всем комментаторам. Тогда, как я понял, это должно делаться через Api, есть уже готовые решения для этого?

Comment: Просто в MailNet есть метод, который аутенфицирует пользователя, и отельный метод который подключается к смтп серверу, вот я и думал, что может а маилнет это как-то реализовано

Comment: `ведь список почтовых сервисов невероятно большой` - да, и каждый имеет свои методы, свои настройки, свои протоколы безопасности. Не ищите универсальных решений, ищите конкретно под нужный сервис то, что вам надо. Переадресация - это функционал именно почтового сервиса, а не клиента, при приходе письма на сервер, уже тот решает пересылать или нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ оказался проще, чем казалось.

При отправке письма, к нему можно прикрепить Header, существует заголовок [x-forwarder](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For#:~:text=X%2DForwarded%2DFor%20is%20also,other%20accounts%20(probably%20automatically)). Благодаря нему, можно сделать так, чтобы когда адресат нажимал на кнопку ответить, в поле адресат подставлялся email указанный в этом заголовке